# Verbo impersonale che regge verbo impersonale: costruzione implicita?

Tags: grammar, verbs

Ho letto la seguente frase in *Quel ramo del lago di Como…*, capitolo 30º, dell'ottimo Ermanno Detti:

> «Gli era capitato altre volte di sembrargli di vedere o sentire una persona quando desiderava incontrarla e poi rendersi conto di essersi sbagliato»

La frase avrebbe potuto essere:

> «Gli era capitato altre volte **che gli sembrasse** di vedere o sentire una persona quando desiderava incontrarla e di rendersi poi conto di essersi sbagliato»

e non avrebbe destato perplessità sul piano grammaticale, a parte la contorsione/involuzione sintattica che forse riflette lo stato d'animo interiore del protagonista.

Invece quella di Detti mi sembra una costruzione alquanto bizzarra (forse volutamente provocatoria?): entrambi i verbi *capitare* e *sembrare* sono impersonali. In questo caso la costruzione implicita (verbo + preposizione "di" + verbo al modo infinito) è ammissibile, si tratta di una forzatura, o è un errore?

Conoscete altri casi in cui sia stata usata una costruzione simile?

---

---

Grazie per le risposte. Riporto qui alcune precisazioni che potrebbero essere utili.

Le tre proposizioni si possono riscrivere così:

> «Era capitato a lui che a lui sembrasse che lui vedesse»

cioè

> «Gli era capitato che gli sembrasse che (lui) vedesse»

L'[Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-impersonali_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) ci spiega che *sembrare* è un verbo impersonale; e anche *[capitare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/capitare/)* lo è. Alcuni esempi che fa la Treccani sono:

> «mi sembra di star meglio»
>
> «mi càpita spesso di dimenticare le chiavi»

Non c'è dubbio quindi che *capitare* e *sembrare* siano due verbi impersonali.

La Treccani dà una regola molto chiara:

> I verbi che formano una proposizione soggettiva come *sembrare*, *parere*, *risultare*, *accadere*, *succedere* possono trovarsi in proposizioni sia implicite, sia esplicite.
>
> • Si trovano in una proposizione *implicita*:
>
> – quando il significato della frase è pienamente impersonale
>
> sembra di volare, successe di perdere la strada
>
> – quando il soggetto logico della proposizione principale coincide con il soggetto grammaticale della proposizione soggettiva
>
> Mi sembra di star meglio (= a me sembra che io stia meglio)
>
> Gli succede di svegliarsi di notte (= a lui succede che lui si svegli di notte)»

E ci siamo, il problema è proprio questo: il **soggetto logico** di *capitare* coincide con il **soggetto logico** di *sembrare* (e *vedere*) ma non con il suo **soggetto grammaticale**. Infatti il **soggetto grammaticale** di *gli era capitato* è *che gli sembrasse*; il **soggetto grammaticale** di quest'ultimo è *che (lui) vedesse* dove *lui* è **soggetto grammaticale** di *vedesse*.

La regola enunciata dalla Treccani nulla dice circa il caso in cui *il soggetto logico della proposizione principale coincida con il soggetto logico della proposizione soggettiva ma non con il suo soggetto grammaticale*.

È proprio come se l'autore, sapendolo, facesse l'occhiolino e dicesse «e adesso dimostratemi che non si può dire!».

Comment: sembrare è _anche_ impersonale, ma non qui: 'sembra a...' è intransitivo, 'sembra che...' è impersonale. Ho citato un esempio. Se rimuovi questa premessa, tutti i tuoi dubbi vengono meno.

Comment: Per piacere controlla il riferimento alla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/verbi-impersonali_(La_grammatica_italiana)/) («I verbi che formano una proposizione soggettiva come _sembrare_, _parere_, _risultare_, _accadere_, _succedere_ possono trovarsi in proposizioni sia implicite, sia esplicite. […] Mi sembra di star meglio […] Gli sembrò che non avrebbe ceduto»). Poi il verbo _sembrare_ può diventare personale in alcuni casi («Sembra che il computer si sia acceso --> Il computer sembra essersi acceso»).

Comment: Nel titolo si fa riferimento ad una costruzione implicita in cui un 1º verbo impersonale regge un 2º verbo impersonale: si tratta di una costruzione anomala. Nella tua risposta contestavi tali premesse, per questo avevo cercato di discuterne, forse finendo per dilungarmi troppo. Della tua risposta avrei senz'altro salvato l'esempio _«Gli era capitato di sembrargli di vedere un gatto»_: in questi giorni mi sono chiesto se almeno in italiano medioevale o forse in qualche dialetto questa costruzione sia ammissibile. Ho persino scandagliato alcuni testi classici ma ahimé non ho trovato risposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A me sembra "un errore" o perlomeno una costruzione volutamente stridente dal punto di vista sintattico.

`Gli era capitato di sembrargli` vorrebbe dire in modo naturale un'altra cosa. Poniamo che Marco sia il padre di Matteo. Matteo è un adulto e Marco è ormai anziano. Marco fa fatica ad alzarsi dal letto e chiede aiuto al figlio. La voce narrante commenta:

> Gli era capitato altre volte di sembrargli vecchio, ma mai così tanto.
>   Marco sapeva che Matteo lo vedeva ormai come una mummia decrepita.

Il lui a cui capita è il soggetto della subordinata e quindi non è lo stesso lui a cui sembra qualcosa. Se volessimo dire che Marco sembra vecchio a sé stesso, useremmo appunto la forma riflessiva:

> Gli era capitato altre volte di sembrarsi vecchio, ma mai così tanto.

Ha un suono strano, perché la soluzione più ovvia sarebbe semmai `sentirsi` e non `sembrarsi`, ma non è sbagliato né ambiguo. Il punto è che se la subordinata ha l'infinito il soggetto logico resta lo stesso della principale.

La prosecuzione della frase, certo, toglie l'ambiguità, perché c'è una subordinata della subordinata (`vedere o sentire`), anche questa all'infinito, e quindi anche questa che eredita lo stesso soggetto logico delle due precedenti. Leggendo la frase così com'è dunque sappiamo che a X capita qualcosa e che X vede/sente qualcosa, ci tocca per forza dedurre, a dispetto della sintassi, che *a X sembra qualcosa* (e non che *X sembra qualcosa*), e per l'appunto gli sembra di vedere/sentire.

Sembra difficile credere che l'errore sia passato inosservato all'autore: è voluto e mi sembra buona l'ipotesi che volesse esprimere un pensiero contorto usando una sintassi contorta. Del resto stiamo parlando di tre "forse" di fila (gli capita, gli sembra e poi c'è anche una disgiunzione... ma alla fine si era sbagliato).

Comment: Mauro, solo una piccola osservazione: applicando la regola della Treccani che cito su, si dovrebbe dire «Gli era capitato altre volte che (il padre) gli sembrasse vecchio». Infatti il **soggetto logico** della proposizione principale (lui) non coincide con il **soggetto grammaticale** della proposizione soggettiva (il padre), e quindi la forma implicita non sarebbe ammissibile.

Comment: Hai ragione, se quello a cui è capitato è il figlio. Ma se si vuole dire che *al padre* è capitato di sembrare vecchio al figlio, si potrebbe dire «Gli era capitato altre volte di sembrargli vecchio». Il significato delle due frasi è lo stesso ma magari la voce narrante sta "seguendo" i pensieri del padre e non quelli del figlio.

Comment: Ok, avevo frainteso - adesso ha senso. Grazie!

Comment: Grazie a te! Credo che la tua osservazione finale nella domanda sia molto appropriata: *È proprio come se l'autore, sapendolo, facesse l'occhiolino e dicesse «e adesso dimostratemi che non si può dire!»*.

Comment: Mi sa che ci hai visto giusto. L'argomentazione che mi convince è proprio quella iniziale: «Gli era capitato di sembrargli» propriamente significherebbe che ad **A** era capitato di sembrare a **B** (dove, se capisco bene, _[sembrare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sembrare_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)_ sarebbe qui verbo copulativo).

Comment: Sì. Nel mio esempio è copulativo, nel brano di Detti no; in quella costruzione, però, la forma non copulativa non potrebbe stare. Il gioco tra queste due forme, quella che ti aspetteresti e quella che invece c'è anche se non dovrebbe, a me sembra necessariamente voluto. Comunque è interessante quanto si dice [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/frasi-completive_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) sulla instabilità della forma del tipo *Mi dispiace di essere*.